# Set up VM to copy mouse movements without capturing them

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is there a way to set up a virtual machine to copy mouse movements without capturing them (i.e. so I could be moving my mouse around outside of the VM and the same movements would happen in the VM)?

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's fair, but I don't think there is - I'm trying to send legitimate mouse movements to a program, and copying my own actual mouse movements seems to be the only reasonable way of generating real ones.